# Inconsistent UITableViewCell Size When Updating Cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

When I attempt to update my table `**UITableview**` using the code below my cells become smaller. I was wondering if anyone has faced the same problem and would know why this is happening.

```
 NSMutableArray* indexPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 for (int i = 20; i < 20 + 20; i++) {
     [indexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
 }

 [self.tableView beginUpdates];
 [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimationBottom)];
 [self.tableView endUpdates];
```

....

Comment: It may be auto layout issue are you checked it ?

Comment: This is wha I suspect but I don't know where to start from. It restores to normal who i scroll down though. It may be worth noting that I am using a custom `TableViewCell` class. And in the setFrame I set some 
`
    - (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame {
        frame.origin.x += 5;
       frame.origin.y += 5;
       frame.size.width -= 2 * 5;
       frame.size.height -= 2 * 5;
       [super setFrame:frame];
    }
`

Comment: I post answer for adjust auto layout. which may solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

@CreativityKills.

if your auto layout is on please try following method to add after add rows. It may help you if it was a problem of auto-layout.

```
 NSMutableArray* indexPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 for (int i = 20; i < 20 + 20; i++) {
     [indexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
 }

 [self.tableView beginUpdates];
 [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimationBottom)];
 [self.tableView endUpdates];
 [self adjustHeightOfTableview];


- (void)adjustHeightOfTableview
{
    CGFloat height = self.tableView.contentSize.height;
    CGFloat maxHeight = self.tableView.superview.frame.size.height - self.tableView.frame.origin.y;

    // if the height of the content is greater than the maxHeight of
    // total space on the screen, limit the height to the size of the
    // superview.

    if (height > maxHeight)
        height = maxHeight;

    // now set the height constraint accordingly

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        self.tableViewHeightConstraint.constant = height;
        [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    }];
}
```

Hope this may help you.

Comment: Hello thanks for your response, i think you are on the right track but the height is already solid, its the width that changes.

Comment: @CreativityKills can you change same function to width.

Comment: I tried that and didn't work. I removed the insets all together and it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

May be you have not given implementation for UITableViewDelegate method:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat 
{
    return 44.0;//your default row height
}
```